# SHTML and JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, include-path, shtml

I am having a problem with my javascript not working inside my includes file that is a SHTML file. This is for a class I am tacking, but any way since we do not have SSI we have to use SHTML so we can use #includes here is what I have. I have just like the book ask but is not working. now this is my head document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- head_document.shtml -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <base href="http://studentwebfiles.us/CPM190/MSchultz/ssi/index.shtml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablet.css"
      media="screen and (max-width: 900px)">
    <script src="scripts/feedbackFormValidate.js"></script> 
    <title> Every Little Detail Auto Supplies - USA's Largest Supplier</title>  
</head>
```

now this is my feedback.shtml file. Everything works beside the javascript

```
include virtual="../common/document_head.shtml"-->
<body>
    <header>
        <!--#include virtual="../common/logo_row.shtml"--> 
        <!--#include virtual="../common/mainmenu_row.shtml"-->
    </header>
    <h3>Customer Feedback Form</h3>
    <form id="contactForm" onsubmit="feedbackFormValidate()">
        <table>
                <tr>
                <td>Salutation:</td>
                <td><select name="salute">
                <option>&nbsp;</option>
                <option>Mrs.</option>
                <option>Ms.</option>
                <option>Mr.</option>
                <option>Dr.</option>
                </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="40"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName" size="40"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>E-mail Address:</td>
                <td><input name="email" size="40" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Phone Number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone" size="40"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Subject:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subject" size="40"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Comments:</td>
                <td><textarea cols="30" name="message" rows="6"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Please check here if you wish to receive a reply: 
                <input type="checkbox"  name="reply" value="yes"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Send Feedback"></td>
                <td class="RightAligned">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset Form"></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <footer>
        <!--#include virtual="../common/footer_row.shtml"-->
    </footer>
</body>
```

This is my . js file

```
function feedbackFormValidate()
{
var contactFormObj = document.getElementById("contactForm");
var firstName = contactFormObj.firstName.value;
var lastName = contactFormObj.lastName.value;
var phone = contactFormObj.phone.value;
var email = contactFormObj.email.value;
var everythingOK = true;

if (!validateName(firstName))
{
    alert("Error: Invalid first name.");
    everythingOK = false;
}

if (!validateName(lastName))
{
    alert("Error: Invalid last name.");
    everythingOK = false;
}

if (!validatePhone(phone))
{
    alert("Error: Invalid phone number.");
    everythingOK = false;
}

if (!validateEmail(email))
{
    alert("Error: Invalid e-mail address.");
    everythingOK = false;
}

if (everythingOK)
{
    if (contactFormObj.reply.checked)
        alert("Warning: The e-mail feature is currently not supported.");
    alert("All the information looks good.\nThank you!");
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
}

function validateName(name)
{
var p = name.search(/^[-'\w\s]+$/);
if (p == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

function validatePhone(phone)
{
var p1 = phone.search(/^\d{3}[-\s]{0,1}\d{3}[-\s]{0,1}\d{4}$/);
var p2 = phone.search(/^\d{3}[-\s]{0,1}\d{4}$/);
if (p1 == 0 || p2 == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

function validateEmail(address)
{
var p = address.search(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})$/);
if (p == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

any help or ideas would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

figured it out Ipages keep kicking out onsubmit.